# How to view all tracked visitors in Google Analytics in main URL without tracking code

Tags: url, google-analytics

We use Marketo and it adds an ID for every unique visitor. This presents a problem when I want to view all visitors that have filled out our contact form. The main page is:

```
/EnterpriseDemoRequest_ThankyouConfirm.html
```

So when I get results from Google on the thank you page it shows up like so in a giant list like below:

```
...
78. /ContactSales_ThankyouConfirm.html?aliId=25026187
79. /ContactSales_ThankyouConfirm.html?aliId=25027907
80. /ContactSales_ThankyouConfirm.html?aliId=25028288
81. /ContactSales_ThankyouConfirm.html?aliId=25028314
...
```

Hoping someone can help me figure out how to filter out the tracking code beyond `/EnterpriseDemoRequest_ThankyouConfirm.html`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should `aliId` as an excluded URL query parameter in Admin > Profile > Settings:

[image]

This change is to be done at the "Profile" (now labelled "View") level. As such, it will only apply to future data.